# React Native - seeing stuff load

Tags: react-native

This might be kinda an awkward question as I am not sure the best way to phrase this..

My React Native app does a decent amount of pulling from a server.. its a social app, sometimes when I load a page in the app that is pulling a decent amount of data from a server you can kinda see stuff loading in.. like almost kinda slowly

Is their a solution to this, maybe a way so it dosen't even render the page until its completely done loading? Or is the solution some sort of loading animation? Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a UX problem and therefore needs a solution such as an activity indicator or overlay with a loading message. Also like Facebook's newsfeed approach, you can display default empty cards so as to make users know that the page is loading.

Comment: didn't know if there was something besides componentdidload or some function that comes super early.. yeah guess itll have to be overlay loading message.. its usually pretty fast

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to avoid premature content flashing is to render the content only after fetching is completed. Below is an example component demonstrating this idea.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fetchData: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        dataFetched: false
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.fetchData();

    this.setState({dataFetched: true});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.dataFetched ?
          <Text>Fetched</Text> :
          null
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```